# Sell bitcoin to account

Tags: address-reuse

So let's say I have multiple bitcoin addresses (some of them already received bitcoins), created a new bitcoin address, received bitcoins on it and would like to use the very same address to send them elsewhere - how can I do that?

Comment: Does very same address means the newly generated address?

Answer (score 1):

Most wallets don't pay attention to which addresses you "send from", and for most purposes it doesn't matter.  When you try to send coins, they will select inputs from among all the transactions paid to all your addresses, hopefully in such a way as to minimize your transaction fees in the long run.

However, some wallets, such as Bitcoin Core, have a "coin control" feature that lets you manually select the inputs for a new outgoing transaction.  You could use this to choose only inputs that come from your desired address.  But in most cases there isn't any need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

your question is very vague and it is hard to help because you have not specified your bitcoin wallet, so I will assume you are new to this.

Yes-just like cash you can transfer bitcoins from one wallet to another.

To do this, you will need:

1. Your bitcoin address
2. The private key associated to it (think password)

Most wallets keep your private key stored for you, so you really only need to be able to access your wallet.

Finally, because you have not specisified what wallet you are using, the next step can vary.

Most wallets today have a simple send button. Simply type the address you want to send coins to (from a wallet that has a balance), and type in how much you want to send.

From the looks of your question, it seems like you lost private key or don't have access to the wallet. If this is the case, the coins are lost forever.